# Expected values using a poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> A doctor has appointments at 9 and 9:30. The amount of time each appointment lasts is exponential with mean 30 minutes. What is the expected amount of time after 9:30 until the 2nd patient has completed his appointment?

My idea here is to condition on the first appointment taking more than (and less than) 30 minutes. Thus, where $T$ is the amount of time after 9:30 until both appointments are done, and $t_1$ is the time appointment 1 takes, $$E[T] = E[E[T | t_1]] = E[T | t_1 < 30] * P(t_1 < 30) + E[T | t_1 > 30] * P(t_1 > 30)$$ Breaking it down a bit, we see that $$P(t_1 < 30) = (1 - \frac{1}{e}), P(t_1 > 30) = \frac{1}{e}$$ Further, $$E[T | t_1 < 30] = \frac{1}{\lambda} = 30$$ However, this $E[T | t_1 > 30]$ is giving me problems. I would think we should apply the memoryless property here; that is, given the first appointment has already taken 30 minutes, we expect that the 2 appointments together will take 60 *more* minutes. That is, $$E[T | t_1 > 30] = 2 * \frac{1}{\lambda} = 60$$ This gives me that the expected amount of minutes past 9:30 until the 2nd appointment is done is approximately 41.04 minutes.

I'm fairly confident in everything other than my calculation of $E[T | t_1 > 30]$. Have I gone wrong here, or is this answer correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why all the craze with conditionings? These mainly seem like occasions of going wrong... so, let us keep things simple and let us start from the fact that you are after the mean of $$T=(t_1-30)^++t_2$$ where $t_i$ is the length of appointment $i$, $t^+=\max(t,0)$, and $t_1$ and $t_2$ are both exponential with parameter $\frac1{30}$. Each $t_i$ is distributed like $30\,t_0$ where $t_0$ is standard exponential, hence $$E(T)=30\,E((t_0-1)^+)+30\,E(t_0)$$ One should definitely know that $E(t_0)=1$, and one can compute 
$$E((t_0-1)^+)=\int_1^\infty (t-1)\,e^{-t}dt=\left.-te^{-t}\right|_1^\infty=e^{-1}$$ Finally, $$E(T)=30\,(1+e^{-1})$$
*Nota:* Of course, one could also use the fact that $t_0-1$ conditionally on $t_0>1$ is distributed as $t_0$, hence $$E((t_0-1)^+)=E(t_0)\cdot P(t_0>1)=1\cdot e^{-1}$$ but this does not sem like a major simplification.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! The form of your answer, $$E(T) = 30(1 + e^{-1})$$ really helps me to understand the solution intuitively; the expected amount of time after 9:30 is simply 30 minutes (for appointment 2) and 30 minutes times the probability that appointment 1 lasts longer than 30 minutes. Really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the appointments take $t_1$ and $t_2$, and $S$ is total time elapsed to the end of the second appointment. Then $T = S - 30$ and
$$
\mathbb{E}[S | t_1 < 30] = 30 + \mathbb{E}[t_2] = 60.
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[S | t_1 > 30]
 = \mathbb{E}[t_1 + t_2 | t_1 > 30]
 = \mathbb{E}[t_1 | t_1 > 30] + 30 > 60.
$$

Comment: The OP has defined $T$ as the amount of time after 9:30.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist fixed

Comment: So this last expectation, $E[t_1 | t_1 > 30]$ is the expectation that I'm unsure about. Can we apply the memoryless property here? Thus, given $t_1 > 30$, the process restarts so that $E[S | t_1 > 30] = 3 * \frac{1}{\lambda} = 90$. Is this correct?

Comment: @mizichael not quite. Try calculating the density of $t_1$ conditional on $t_1 > 30$. You can compute the expectation directly from that.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I'm sorry but I'm simply not sure how to go about finding this density. Is there potentially any identity or theorem you could point me towards to help me out?